# CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION during inserting calendar event not working

Tags: android, android-intent, google-calendar-api

I have wrote code for inserting calendar event programmatically, which is working fine, Events are added first to device calendar app and then synced with calendar account, and I can check my calendar events synced with it.

```
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, DateUtils.getServerTimeInDate(visitTask.getStartDate()));
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, DateUtils.getServerTimeInDate(visitTask.getEndDate()));
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "calendar title");
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "XYZ");
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, selectedCalendarId);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.ALL_DAY, false);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.STATUS, 1);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, true);
```

And when i check my google calendar account, everything get synced with account, but location field when checked with google calendear does not appear online, startTime, EndTime everything works fine.

Just an issue EVENT_LOCATION.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a bug in the sync adapter installed with the latest version of the Calendar app and has been [reported elsewhere](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79840). May want to watch that bug for updates.